# Is there an intervalometer which will work with a Canon PowerShot SX60?

Tags: canon, equipment-recommendation, powershot, intervalometer

I'm look for an intervalometer that works with a Canon PowerShot SX60.  I want to do some timelapse photography.  I'm not having much luck locating one.  Does anyone know of such a device?

Answer (score 3):

Two ways you might do this:

1. According to [PC World, a smart phone or tablet can control the camera.](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2470532,00.asp) "You can zoom the lens, set the self-timer, control the flash output, and fire the shutter." If you can find (or write) an app to do this, you have a free intervalometer.
2. [CHDK (*Canon Hack Development Kit*)](http://chdk.wikia.com/wiki/CHDK) can be installed from memory card in a few minutes. This makes no permanent change to the camera firmware; the card can be removed and reformatted as needed. [There is a tutorial for time lapse photography using CHDK.](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-To-Take-Time-Lapse-Photos-CHDK/)

So either way, this should cost you nothing to try.

Answer (score 2):

The Canon Powershot SX60 has a 2.5mm cable release port, like any Canon dRebel does. Any cable intervalometer that works with a Canon dRebel should also work with the SX60.

Answer (score 0):

Does that camera have a plug for a cable release?  If it works as a simple push-button, you could use any common/cheap intervalometer and add an adaptor for the plug needed.

Does it *not* have such a jack?  Then how do you expect to hook it up at all? If it takes commands over USB *and* uses the fairly new USB profile for standardizing that, then I've seen high-end intervalometers that use USB.

No plug at all? Use Lego to build a gizmo to push the button, and program it using the mindstorm brick or have it commanded by a plain intervalometer that works by connecting 2 pins on a jack.

Comment: Many years ago strap on cable releases were a thing. They didn't work very well on all cameras. You'd still need a means of actuating it, but they also existed. So the "no jack" situation isn't a complete lockout.

Answer (score -1):

try the ShutterBoss II Timer Remote Switch for canon...it may work for you

Comment: Take note that there are versions with various connectors, and you need the 2.5mm cable version (see inkista's answer).